# Multi-host Docker network with Swarm-mode and without swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am migrating legacy application deployed on two physical servers[web-app(node1) and DB(node2)].

Though following blog fullfilled my requirement. but still some questions

https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/multi-host-docker-network-without-swarm/#comment-2833

1- For mentioned scenario web-app(node1) and DB(node2), we can use expose port options and webapp will use that port, why to create overlay network?

2- By using swarm-mode with replica=1 we can achieve same, so what advantage we will get by using creating overlay network without swarm mode?

3- if node on which consul is installed, it goes down our whole application is no more working.(correct if understanding is wrong)

4- In swarm-mode if manager node goes down(which also have webapp) my understanding is swarm will launch both containers on available host? please correct me if my understanding is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article is describing an outdated mode of operation for 'Swarm'. What's described is 'Classic Swarm' that needed an external kv store (like consul) but now Docker primarily uses 'Swarm mode' (which is an orchestration capability built in to the engine itself). To answer what I think your questions are:

1. I think you're asking, if we can expose a port for a service on a host, why do we need an overlay network? If so, what happens if the host goes down and the container gets re-scheduled to another node? The overlay network takes care of that by keeping track of where containers are and routing traffic appropriately.
2. Not sure what you mean by this.
3. If consul was a key piece of discovery infra then yes, it would be a single point of failure so you'd want to run it HA. This is one of the reasons that the dependency on an external kv was removed with 'Swarm Mode'.
4. Not sure what you mean by this, but maybe about rebalancing? If so then yes, if a host (with containers) goes down, those containers will be re-scheduled on another node.